# Joomla 2.5 Blank page

Tags: php, joomla2.5

My website was working well but now it displays just blank page. Also the admin page doesn't work properly. 
At least to have some errors to see what is going on, I added this line of code at index.php:

```
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE); error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and what is showed are these erros:

String Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/.../rsform.php on line 39
String Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/.../rsform.php on line 66
String Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/.../rsform.php on line 74 
Fatal Error: Allowed memory size 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/.../public_html/libraries/phputf8/utils/unicode.php on line 49

Any solution for that.

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the Strict Standard errors:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/.../rsform.php on line 39
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/.../rsform.php on line 66
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/.../rsform.php on line 74
```

I'm assuming you are using PHP 5.4+. Joomla 2.5 has comparability issues with versions above PHP 5.3. I suggesting trying PHP 5.3, that should resolve the issues for you. You can also disable these error_reporting warnings by adding the following to your php.ini file:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

As for the memory exhaustion message:

```
Fatal Error: Allowed memory size 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/.../public_html/libraries/phputf8/utils/unicode.php on line 49
```

That basically means that your website is running out of memory allocated by your host. You can contact your host regarding this and ask them to configure PHP with a higher value for memory_limit. There are also other ways you can do this, if your host allows this:

- Adding the init_set('memory_limit', $amount_of_memory) in your index.php file.
- Setting the memory_limit Apache variable at the .htaccess level using the php_value
- Modifying the global/local php.ini and setting the value of memory_limit to a higher amount.